# Simply Import Task with Celery

Tags: django, django-celery

I have a simple view which uploads CSV data to a mapped model and populates the data. This works perfect, but now I want to integrate [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/) and I'm really struggling to get the following task to work. I'm trying Celery with Django and [Amazon SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).

This is the main part of my `view.py` which runs the task:

```
    def upload(request):
        # If we had a POST then get the request post values.
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ContactUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            # Check we have valid data
            if form.is_valid():

                filename = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])

                import_csv.delay(filename)

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('name.csv', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

**This was my 1st attempt at the task.py**

```
@task
def import_csv(filename):
    ContactCSVModel.import_from_file(filename)
```

Which gives the error in the celery log: **`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'`**

My second attempt I think won't work because it actually trying to upload the file to SQS  and gives `SQSError: 413 Request Entity Too Large`. I'm assuming this is not what I want to do at all, its a task and I don't want to upload the file to SQS.

**2nd attempt at task.py**

```
@task
def import_csv(filename):
    ContactCSVModel.import_data(data = open(filename))
```

**3rd attempted at task.py by passing in the request instead**

```
@task
def import_csv(request):
    filename = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
    ContactCSVModel.import_data(data = open(filename))
```

This give the error `**Can't pickle <type 'cStringIO.StringO'>: attribute lookup cStringIO.StringO failed**`

**How can I achieve this task?** I'm sure it's something very simple :) As you can see I have tried a few different things above to create this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this example: http://codeinthehole.com/writing/use-models-for-uploads/

Create a new model to handle the file upload and use celery to run the import, this way the task is just the job id

```
@task
def process_upload(upload_id):
    upload = Uploads.objects.get(id=upload_id)
    upload.process()
```